# Spring Security BCrypt Password Encoder - Workload Factor

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm integrating Spring Security's Bcrypt Password Encoder into a new application, and while testing I noticed that the workload doesn't seem to have an effect when matching a password using two encoders with different work factors.  Take the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PasswordEncoder strongEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    PasswordEncoder weakEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(6);

    String password = "SomePassword@@";

    String strongEncodedPass = strongEncoder.encode(password);
    String weakEncodedPass = weakEncoder.encode(password);

    //Prints true
    System.out.println(weakEncoder.matches(password, strongEncodedPass)); 
    //Prints true
    System.out.println(strongEncoder.matches(password, weakEncodedPass)); 
}
```

Shouldn't both print statements results in false since the encoders are using different work loads?

The above sample was tested using spring-security-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar in Java 8

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the wikipedia article on BCrypt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), you'll notice that the format of the hash contains the number of rounds

> For example, the shadow password record `$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy` specifies a cost parameter of 10, indicating 210 key expansion rounds. The salt is N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMye and the resulting hash is IjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy.

So, when veryfing if a password matches a hash, it is hashed a similar number of times as the original hash.

In other words: the `matches()` is independent of the setup, and could probably be static...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source code, the strength is only used when generating the salt. The number of rounds used by the encryption algorithm itself is hard-coded to 16.

So what you see is expected. Not sure why Spring didn't allow choosing a number of rounds for the encryption part, though. It might be worth signalling that in a bug/feature request, because the documentation is indeed confusing.